# FileInput: Make backup files only for files in directory that have been worked on

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io, replace, backup

I am using os.walk to walk through a directory searching for certain filetypes.  Once a filetype has been found (such as .txt or .xml), I want to use this definition to replace the strings (let's call it `old`) in the file with the strings from a dictionary (let's call it `new`).

```
def multipleReplace(text, wordDict):
    for key in wordDict:
        text = text.replace(key, wordDict[key])
    return text
```

At first, I had this loop:

```
myDict = #dictionary with keys(old) and values(new)#
home = #some directory#
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(home):
    for Filename in filenames:
        filename = os.path.join(dirpath, Filename)
        if filename.endswith('.txt') or filename.endswith('.xml'):
                with fileinput.FileInput(filename,inplace=True,backup='.bak') as file:
                    for line in file:
                        print(multipleReplace(line,myDict),end='')
```

This worked quickly and would replace the `old` strings with the `new` strings in every file that it found the `old` strings in.  However, the problem lies in my script creating a .bak file for every file, regardless of whether or not it even found the `old` strings in them.

I want to create a .bak file only for the files that contain the `old` strings (only for files where the replacement was done).
I tried to read all the files and append only those that contained the `old` strings (using something like `newFiles.append(re.findall('\\b'+old+'\\b',line))` that way I could use the FileInput method for those files only,but the regex look up takes forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think regex is necessary here. The only missing part is to check if the file contains `old` strings before creating a .bak file. So, please try the following approach:

```
def multipleReplace(text, wordDict):
    for key in wordDict.keys(): # the keys are the old strings
        text = text.replace(key, wordDict[key])
    return text

myDict = #dictionary with keys(old) and values(new)#
home = #some directory#
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(home):
    for Filename in filenames:
        filename = os.path.join(dirpath, Filename)
        if filename.endswith('.txt') or filename.endswith('.xml'):
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                content = f.read() # open and read file content
            if any([key in content for key in wordDict.keys()]):  # check if old strings are found              
                with fileinput.FileInput(filename,inplace=True,backup='.bak') as file:
                    for line in file:
                        print(multipleReplace(line,myDict), end='')
```